# change artifactory temp uploads directory

Tags: artifactory

I am searching for an answer to a question: How can I change artifactory temp uploads path? changing Tomcat java-temp does not bring anything because all my uploads are stored temporary here: (...)\artifactory-pro-5.2.1\data\tmp\artifactory-uploads and my C drive is too small for my uploads.

If anyone knew how to change it e.g. to E drive or wherever else  I would be very grateful,

B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure the temp uploads directory in Windows OS. This is always under the `%ARTIFACTORY_HOME%\data\tmp\artifactory-uploads` directory.
Probably that does not help, but in Linux you can create a symlink to a different mount...

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: Hello Yinon, thanks a million for your answer. I will just get some more space on my Drive then.... have a nice day! B.